# Completely lost on Bootstrap card grid alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am working on a Pinterest clone, where cards of different sizes will shift to different rows based on window size, but I am really struggling aligning cards via Bootstrap.  Anytime I get it to work, I feel like I can't duplicate it on different projects.
Here is my current code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <ul class="card-grid col-lg-6">
     <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <% if pin.photo.attached? %>
      <li class="card"><%= cl_image_tag pin.photo.key, crop: :fill %>
        <% else %>
        <%= image_tag "filler.jpg", class: "card-img" %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="photobottom"><h2><%= link_to pin.title, pin %></h2></div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Using this, all the cards are in one singular column.  If I add this code:

```
.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 16px;

}
```

I can get two cards on the same row, but they are squished and for some reason one car has a huge amount of white space on the bottom.

What am I missing here?  I know this is a very basic question but I always struggle with frontend alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing it in action it's hard to understand what is going on. You mentioned that the that one of the cards have a massive amount of white space. Have you looked at `:first-child` or `:last-child`?

```
// SCSS File...

.card-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 16px;

    // or the first item
    li:first-child {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    // or the last item
    li:last-child {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

}
```

With the padding bottom and margin bottom - this should remove any whitespace for spacing issues..but could effect overall design. It again depends on which element in the list is causing the issue.